# Xamarin Android Reflection Pairing Bluetooth target Exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, system.reflection

I have a little problem with Bluetooth Pairing Confirmation. Here is Java line code, which works fine:

```
// java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission: Neither user 10094 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.
// above perm is only granted to system apps, not third party apps ...
device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
```

But in Xamarin it shows an TagretException when I launch this line

```
device.Class.GetMethod("setPairingConfirmation", new Java.Lang.Class[] { Java.Lang.Boolean.Type }).Invoke(device, Java.Lang.Boolean.True);
```

Does somebody know why this happens? I used a system reflection like

```
device.GetType().GetMethod("SetPairingConfirmation").Invoke(device, new object[] { true });
```

And it doesnt work too. Really confused.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it much more complicated that it really is!

You can use just the `SetPairingConfirmation()` function! You just have to make sure that you place a check to run the code if the API level is greater than 19 since `BluetoothDevice` was introduced only then. You might also want to use a different Exception catching like a `Java.IO.IOException`.

```
public bool IsPairingConfirmed(Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice device)
{
    bool confirmation = false;
    try
    {
        if ((int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 19)
            confirmation = device.SetPairingConfirmation(true);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return confirmation;
}
```

I hope this makes sense, and make sure you do everything else right.